# What html parser is able to handle encoding?

Tags: java, html, encoding, html-parsing

This is the beginning -- I have a file on disk which is HTML page. When I open it with regular web browser it displays as it should -- i.e. no matter what encoding is used, I see correct national characters.

Then I come -- my task is to load the same file, parse it, and print out some pieces on the screen (console) -- let's say, all <hX> texts. Of course I would like to see only correct characters, not some mambo-jumbo. The last step is changing some of text, and save the file.

So the parser has to parse and handle encoding in both ways as well. So far I am unaware of parser which is even capable of loading data correctly.

## Question

What parser would you recommend?

### Details

HTML page in general has the encoding given in header (in meta tag), so parser should use it. The scenario I have to look in advance and check the encoding, and then manually set the encoding in code is no-go. For example, this is taken from JSoup tutorials:

```
File input = new File("/tmp/input.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");
```

I cannot do such thing, parser has to handle encoding detection by itself.

---

*In C# I faced similar problem with loading html. I used HTMLAgilityPack and first executed encoding detection, then using it I encoded the data stream, and after that I parsed the data. So, I did both steps explicitly, but since the library delivers both methods it is fine with me.*

*Such explicit separation might be even better, because it would be possible to use in case of missing header probabilistic encoding detection method.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Jsoup API reference says for that parse method that if you provide `null` as the second argument (the encoding one), it'll use the `http-equiv` meta-tag to determine the encoding. So it looks like it already does the "parse a bit, determine encoding, re-parse with proper encoding" routine. Normally such parsers should be capable of resolving the encoding themselves using any means available to them. I know that SAX parsers in Java are supposed to use byte-order marks and the XML declaration to try and establish an encoding.

Apparently Jsoup will default to UTF-8 if no proper meta-tag is found. As they say in the documentation, this is "usually safe" since UTF-8 is compatible with a host of common encodings for the lower code points. But I take it that "usually safe" might not really be good enough in this case.

If you don't sufficiently trust Jsoup to detect the encoding, I see two alternatives:

- Should you somehow be ascertained that the HTML is always in fact XHTML, then an XML parser might prove a better fit. But that would only work if the input is definitely XML compliant.
- Do a heuristic encoding detection yourself by trying to use byte-order marks, parsing a portion using common encodings and finding a meta-tag, detecting the encoding by byte patterns you'd expect in header tags and finally, all else failing, use a default.

Comment: No, no, it is not the matter of trusting, I simply saw hard coded UTF8 as was turned off. I will check it then in a second, many thanks! I already tried TagSoup+scala.XML, but I don't see any place for encoding detection, and defaults are broken (i.e. national characters are displayed incorrectly). **Update:** I tested it, works beautifully. Once again -- thank you.